# jQuery Validate Group Messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've browsed through other stackoverflow (and others) problems relating the validate groups but none work or are what I'm looking for.

I have a username and a password field, each with their own error messages. However, if neither are valid, I would like a combined message. I've tried creating a group and I can't even get that to work (combining the two grouped messages whilst retaining individual error messages), let alone a custom message for the group. Any ideas? Here's my relevant code:

```
groups: {
    combined: "loginemail loginuserpw"
},

rules: {                    
    loginemail: {
        required: true, 
        email: true   
    },  
    loginuserpw: { 
        required: function(element) {
            return $('input[name="logintype"]:checked').val() == 'return';
        }
    }
},

messages: { 
    loginemail: {
        required: "'.T_ERR_EMAIL.'",
        email: "'.T_ERR_EMAIL_INVALID.'"
    },                          
    loginuserpw: {
        required: "'.T_ERR_PASS.'"          
    }               
},          

errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter('#form_container');
}
```